# Replacing row values in numpy array based on index stored in another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays. One stores values and another an index for each row above which I'd like to replace the values in the row with 0. I've been going around in circles.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
              [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])

b = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

I'd like to get this:

```
c =      [[1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
         [6, 7, 8, 0, 0],
         [11, 12, 13, 14, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
              [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])

b = np.array([1, 2, 3])

idxrow,idxcol=np.indices(a.shape)
b2=b[:,None]
mask = idxcol > b2
a[mask]=0
print(a)
```